# What unit should we use when working with (La)TeX and PSTricks to minimize conversion error?

Tags: conversion, paper-size, units, dimensions, unit-of-measure

I want to minimize conversion error when working with PSTricks and (La)TeX. The conversion error really affects the accuracy of bounding box, the thickness of LaTeX's `\fbox` and the thickness of PSTricks stroke.

When I specify a length for

1. page layout dimension: `\paperwidth`, `\paperheight`, `\voffset`, `\hoffset`, `\topskip`, `\parindent`
2. TeX box dimension: `\fboxrule`, `\fboxsep`, `\arrayrulewidth`, etc
3. PSTricks object dimension: `\unit`, `\linewidth`, etc

which unit should we use to minimize the conversion? Should we use a single unit throughout the document?

---

Because the existing answers don't explain how to minimize the conversion error, I will emphasize and rephrase my questions above. Based on the existing answers, my understanding is as follows.

TeX naturally works in `sp` and PostScript works naturally in `bp`. If I want to avoid conversion in TeX block, provide the lengths in `sp`. But if I work in PSTricks block, I must provide the length in `bp`.

However, I have one question:

If I define a `\pspicture` dimension in `bp`, how does PSTricks ask TeX to reserve the space without making a conversion error from `bp` to `sp`?

Comment: You do know that TeX always works internally in `sp` (integer) values, I assume?

Comment: @xport: The TeX part of PSTricks will most likely work in the TeX units (`pt`/`sp`, technically the same thing, just presented differently). However, most of the PSTricks magic is done in PostScript which uses `bp`.

Comment: @xport PSTricks uses PostScript, which uses `bp` (72 points per inch).

Comment: @xport: Are you sure that you don't provide `pt` values to postscript which takes it then as `bp`? PostScript doesn't recognize `pt` as TeX point.

Comment: @Joseph: it is not important, that PS has bp as a default unit. Scaling the user coordinate system allows values in_any_ unit.

Comment: @Herbert: However, there must be the potential of rounding errors. For example, as `pt` an `bp` are almost but not quite identical, it's not possible to represent both as floating point machine numbers.

Comment: @Joseph: I understood it so that PSTricks (the LaTeX package) uses TeX dimension register (or skip registers) internally and adds PostScript code at the beginning to change the coordinate system to TeX points, which are also used in the produced PostScript code representing the `pspicture`. This introduces rounding errors in 1) PostScript itself (i.e. the PostScript interpreter) when applying the coordinate system scaling and 2) should the PS code be generated using `\strip@pt\somedimension` or similar `\the` based code because it only uses a few fractional decimal digits.

Comment: @Martin: We always have rounding errors when working with computers and its binary system. The question is if you would see such rounding problems and I know that you cannot see any problems with the graphical elements as long as you do not use the TeX arithmetic ... And by the way: PDF also uses the bp unit.

Comment: @Herbert: I agree and knew all of that. TeX itself is just not very accurate when it comes to multiplications etc. (16 fractional bits are that much nowadays). But I agree that you normally you don't need the full accuracy and understand why PSTricks uses `pt`. However, during my work on `adjustbox` I learned that `graphics/x` does something like `\edef\somelenwithoutunit{\strip@pt\dimen@}` which introduces unwanted rounding issues for my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(La)TeX itself works only with `pt` (TeX Points, 1pt = 1/72.27 inch). These are *fixed-point numbers* and are internally stored as integers, i.e. multiplied by 65536. These representation is called *scaled points* and have the unit `sp`, so 65536sp = 1pt (because TeX uses 16 bit for the fractional part of a `pt`, 2^16 = 65536) . In other words TeX accuracy is 1/65536 pt = 1sp. Any dimension or calculation which results in a fractional `sp` value is rounded/truncated in an integer value. So 0.01pt = 0.01 * 65536 = 655.36 => 655sp (= 0.009994507pt).
Note that you can display the `sp` representation of a TeX dimension using `\number`, e.g. `\number\textwidth` will give you that value in `sp` but without the unit attached.

If you assign any dimension to a LaTeX length or TeX dimension (defined by `\newlength`, `\newskip` or `\newdimen`) it is converted to `sp` internally (but presented to the user as `pt`), even if you use another unit like `cm`, `bp` or `in`.
This answers your points 1 and 2: it doesn't matter really because it is converted anyway.
If you want to keep it in e.g. `bp` you need to store this value in a macro as string content instead. (`graphics/x` actually does that; it also strips the `bp` unit off)

Postscript rounds the point to simpler fraction: 1 PS pt = 1/72 inch. TeX calls this *big points* because they are slightly larger than TeX points and provides the `bp` unit for it. **If you provide lengths to PostScript code directly, then you need to do this using `bp` not `pt`.** Sometimes it is necessary to strip of the unit in addition (like for the `BoundingBox` header).

I assume the higher level interface of `pstricks` should handle `pt`/`bp` by itself. However, `\special` calls and direct postscript code needs to be handled by yourself. I would keep all units `pt` to avoid rounding errors by TeX and only convert it at the very end if possible.

Comment: You mean by looking at it? Your viewer might not be able to show the difference. There are often also aliasing effects.

Comment: @Martin I hope you don't mind, but I fixed an error in your post: you had a PS point = 72 in. A point is not six feet long...

Comment: @xport: `\message{\number\dimexpr 1bp\relax}` tells me `65781`. See my last update.

Comment: @Seamus: Not at all, thanks for that. I meant "integer fraction" and of course 1/72 not "integer .. 72". Thanks for the correction.

Comment: One should also note that TeX does "truncated division": after `\dimen0=100sp\divide\dimen0 3`, `\dimen0` will be 33sp; after `\dimen0=99sp\divide\dimen0 2`, `\dimen0` will be 49sp. Operations with `\dimexpr` round: `\dimen0=\dimexpr99sp/2\relax` will load 50sp in `\dimen0`. Truncation has some consequences: the well known example of `\hbox to 2in{\hskip 1in\hskip 1in}` results in an "Underfull `\hbox`" message.

Comment: @xport: This means if you use 0.001pt it is stored as 655 instead. In other words, you can't store 0.001pt exactly. This is always the case with binary representation of number which have been input as decimals.

Comment: @xport: The equal to 16 bit, i.e. 2^16 = 65536.

Comment: @xport: The 16bit is used for the fractional part of a point. The whole range is 30bit long (don't ask me why it is not 32bit). The maximum is stored in the constant `\maxdimen`  which is 16383.99999pt or 1073741823sp. If you use 1073741824sp you get an `Dimension too large` error.

Comment: @xport: About your updated question: The way I understand Herbert, the number you give to PSTricks are always converted to `pt` and then to the given unitlength. So you can't avoid the rounding issues apparently.

Comment: @xport: There is no real conversion between `pt` and `sp`. `sp` is just the integer representation of `pt`. If you say `\textwidth=1sp` then the `textwidth` register is set to `1`, if you say `\textwidth=1pt` then it is set to `65536`. You can see `sp` as the internal representation of `pt`, or `pt` as user-friendly display of `sp`.

Comment: @xport: Rounding.

Comment: @Martin: Does it imply that it is better to set any length macros created by `\new*****` to a value in `sp` to avoid rounding?

Comment: @xport: What I meant earlier is that TeX will never be convert from `pt` to `sp` internally. You always have a decimal to binary conversion when you enter fractional values as decimal numbers in the computer. If you want avoid these provide integers only, i.e. `sp` in the case of TeX. However, any calculation will still suffer from numerical rounding errors (as always!). PSTricks seems to set the PostScript unit it `pt` and might truncate the last fractional digits of the numbers.

Comment: @Martin: your statement in 2nd paragraph is contradictory to your last comment. It is really confusing. :-)

Comment: @xport: I already updated my answer accordantly. Again: TeX's default unit is officially `pt` but for technical reasons internally stored as an integer by multiplying it by 65536. That presentation got an own unit name `sp` so you can specify dimensions using the integer representation directly.

Answer (score 3):

PostScript does not know of any unit, everything is in bp. PSTricks can handle values with or without any unit. If a unit is missing the current one is taken into account. PStricks does everything in pt, as TeX itself also does. The PostScript user coordinate system is scaled to pt before all values are passed to PS.

Comment: So `123`, `123bp` and `123pt` would all be taken as 123 / 72 inch by PostScript, wouldn't it? I mean inside PostScript code e.g. inserted by `\special`.

Comment: no, that are 123cm (cm is default unless no other unit is set), 123bp, _and_ 123pt, _three different_ values for PSTricks and for PostScript!